# How to search for any word in a string in Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

So, I have an Access database where full names of patients are stored in a single field, ala "John Henry Michaels".  I would like to be able get a name from the user search for it in the database.  Now, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783094/access-2010-sql-query-find-partial-match-in-string-of-full-word-only) I found this

`WHERE " " & tblEmployee.FullName & " " Like "* " & tblNames.Name & " *"`

which is almost what I want.  The only problem is that if the user doesn't know the middle name and enters "John Michaels", then "John Henry Michaels" will not show up.  Is there a way to search the field for any part of the user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular scenario I would separate the user input and put it in the query as 2 parts (You may need to set up a loop to separate the users input if there is a chance they may enter a name with more than 2 parts).

You would end up with a query that looks like this:

`WHERE " & tblEmployee.FullName & " LIKE '* " & NamePt1 & " *' AND " & tblEmployee.FullName & " LIKE '* " & NamePt2 & " *'"`

Alternatively, you may want to normalize your database and separate the name into 3 parts, as that is the standardized database design.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the nature of the database there is no set limit to the number of names a person can have.  "Michael Daniel Alexander Davis Peterson Johnson" is perfectly valid.  I also can't guarantee two parts being entered, so I'll look into a loop